# Ubuntu 14.04 update failure due to failure in certificate authentication

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, dependencies

Below is the error from running `sudo apt-get update` in a terminal on Ubuntu 14.04:

```
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  
server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
```

As a remedy, I ran the following commands:

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0 libunique-1.0-0 libwebkitgtk-1.0-0
  libwebkitgtk-1.0-common linux-headers-3.13.0-32
  linux-headers-3.13.0-32-generic linux-image-3.13.0-32-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-32-generic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

$ sudo dpkg --purge --force-depends ca-certificates
dpkg: ca-certificates: dependency problems, but removing anyway as you requested:
 python-httplib2 depends on ca-certificates.
 python3-httplib2 depends on ca-certificates.
 software-properties-common depends on ca-certificates.
 ubuntu-desktop depends on ca-certificates.
 libwww-perl depends on ca-certificates.
 liblwp-protocol-https-perl depends on ca-certificates.
 ca-certificates-java depends on ca-certificates (>= 20121114).
python3-requests depends on ca-certificates.
 python-requests depends on ca-certificates.

(Reading database ... 455731 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing ca-certificates (20141019ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
Removing dangling symlinks from /etc/ssl/certs... done.
Purging configuration files for ca-certificates (20141019ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
Removing dangling symlinks from /etc/ssl/certs... done.
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...

$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ca-certificates-java : Depends: ca-certificates (>= 20121114) but it is not installable
 liblwp-protocol-https-perl : Depends: ca-certificates but it is not installable
 libwww-perl : Depends: ca-certificates but it is not installable
 python-httplib2 : Depends: ca-certificates but it is not installable
 python-requests : Depends: ca-certificates but it is not installable
 python3-httplib2 : Depends: ca-certificates but it is not installable
 python3-requests : Depends: ca-certificates but it is not installable
 software-properties-common : Depends: ca-certificates but it is not installable
 ubuntu-desktop : Depends: ca-certificates but it is not installable
                  Recommends: libreoffice-impress but it is not installable
                  Recommends: libreoffice-ogltrans but it is not installable
                  Recommends: libreoffice-presentation-minimizer but it is not installable
                  Recommends: shotwell but it is not installable
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

Now I am feeling more stuck in updating my operating system. I am a newbie to Ubuntu. Can someone please tell me what has gone wrong and how to correct it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed any additional software or drivers, etc.? Try this go to System Settings > Software & Updates and choose another source.

Comment: I was running a regular system update. I didn't install any additional software or drivers. After the problem had occurred (about a week ago) , i had changed System Settings > Software & Updates from "Main Server" to "Server for India" but the problem persisted. Then i again reverted back to the "Main Server". Still the problem persists